# QProcess and Powershell: can't start notepad

Tags: powershell, qt, qprocess

I tried all I could come up with, googled half of the universe etc.

I need to run several commands in Qt from powershell. I open the process and intend to write to stdin. Code below is the simplest case, where I'm trying to simply run notepad.exe. If I replace "powershell" to "cmd" - it works perfectly. But "powershell" is cursed.

> ```
> process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);
> process.start("powershell", QIODevice::ReadWrite);
>
> process.waitForStarted();
> qDebug() << process.readAllStandardOutput();
>
> process.write("notepad\n\r");
> ```

Maybe somebody worked with powershell like this, or have any clue?
Thanks!

Comment: Try `\r\n\r\n` instead of `\n\r`

Comment: Didn't help. btw OS is win 8.1

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your issue in Windows 10 x64, but I couldn't. It works as expected.

Comment: Yeah, possibly it's OS related. Anyway, I used C# after all.